# Django Zappa generated cloudfront generates 403 error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-403, zappa, amazon-cloudfront

I run a Django project deployed on AWS lambda using serverless Zappa framework. This can be accessed by a randomly generated link from AWS API Gateway lets say:-

> randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com/production

I have also created an SSL certificate from ACM and verified it with my domain lets say

> example.com

Now when i run zappa certify, this command certifies my domain successfully and creates a custom domain under API gateway console with the following configurations:-

> Endpoint Configuration Edge optimized
>
> **Target Domain Name** d25ihv8a5022zi.cloudfront.net
>
> **Hosted Zone ID** A2FDTNGATAQYW6
>
> **ACM Certificate** example.com (c504428e)

Now, I need to point my domain name `example.com` to `randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com/production`, so I updated my records on Godaddy with CNAME as follows:-

> TYPE - CNAME NAME - example.com VALUE - d25ihv8a5022zi.cloudfront.net
>   TTL - 1 HOUR

EXPECTED RESULT - My application thats running on `randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com` show be accessable from `example.com`.

WHAT I GET - 403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied. Bad request. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)

EDIT:- So I get rid of zappa created custom domain and created new cloudfront distribution manually as follows:-

> Delivery Method - Web Domain name - d35ihv8a5022fe.cloudfront.net
>   origin - randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com/production cNAMES -
>   example.com Status - Deployed State - Enabled

I did this because zappa generated cloudfront distribution is hidden in AWS console. However, I noticed Zappa generated distribution endpoint gives forbidden when I check the address in browser and the newly created distribution endpoint redirects to my application.

Still, going to example.com gives me 403 error.

Comment: just to make sure, example.com is added as CNAME to Cloudfront and HOST header is not whitelisted.

Comment: Yes, I have added example.com, www.example.com in CNAME to CloudFront. Also checked "cloudfront>behaviors tab> cache based on selected request headers --None" is selected

Comment: After moving to Route 53 and adding CNAME with Alias. I happen to visit www.example.com and it redirects to my application at randomly-generated-link.aws.amazon.com/production. How do I mask this? Do I have to change any cloudfront settings to mask this?

Answer (score 0):

- While debugging I like to keep TTL as short as possible. I'd set the CNAME TTL to 1 minute
- Check that api-gateway custom domain names has your domain listed and you have the Base Path Mappings set correctly.

Base Path Mappings

Path  /
Destination  [lambda endpoint]  .   [production]

It may also be a good idea to host the domain if possible on route53

Comment: I have changed the TTL to 600 seconds on Godaddy console. Now that I have created new distribution on cloudfront(please check edited question) the custom domain of api gateway does'nt allow a new domain to be created and gives "an unexpected error has occured".

Comment: you may need to delete the name in custom domain names and and redeploy with zappa.  Can you drop the TTL to 60 while your testing? Waiting for dns is a pain :)

Comment: Godaddy console gets greyed out when I try to make it 60. I guess 600 is the minimum. So what happens to the custom created distribution when I redeploy/recertify with Zappa? Does Zappa handle this by default?

Comment: As I understand it the cloudfront distribution happens behind the scenes for api gateway. When you redeploy you may get a fresh cloudfront distribution name.

Comment: "An error occurred (TooManyRequestsException) when calling the CreateDomainName operation (reached max retries: 4): Too Many Requests" Now I get this error when I try to certify. I have now moved to route 53 though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a DNS problem anymore, Could it be because Edge optimized uses CloudFront and it takes some time to deploy the new custom domain to all the edge location ? How long have you waited after enabling custom domain name ?

Comment: Also "d25ihv8a5022zi.cloudfront.net" is not resolvable , Have you deleted the config ?

Comment: It has been over 12 hours and Status on AWS console shows Deployed. I have changed my CloudFront endpoint in my question for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I got it working. Moved my Domain nameservers to route53 and in `zappa_settings.json` added

> "route53_enabled": true

and recertified again using `zappa certify production` command.

Had to wait for 40 minutes and it works!

Although, I have no idea why it does'nt work when domain management is with godaddy. Lets say route53 is a quick workaround at the moment.